# How to link verilog blackbox to memory of rocketchip in chisel?

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip

I am trying to attach a verilog module to rocketchip's memory. More precisely, I want to integrate a memory encryption engine as a blackbox. My idea is to link my verilog module to memAXI4Node of trait CanHaveMasterAXI4MemPort and io_axi4 node of SimAXIMem.
The verilog module has IOs for AXI ports, clock and reset.

My first try looks something like this:

SimAXIMem.scala

```
def connectMem(dut: CanHaveMasterAXI4MemPort)(implicit p: Parameters): Seq[SimAXIMem] = {
  dut.mem_axi4.zip(dut.memAXI4Node.in).map { case (io, (_, edge)) =>
  val mem = LazyModule(new SimAXIMem(edge, base =    p(ExtMem).get.master.base, size = p(ExtMem).get.master.size))
  Module(mem.module).suggestName("mem") 
  val blackbox = Module(new MyBlackBox())
  blackbox.io.s_axi_awid := io.aw.bits.id
  blackbox.io.s_axi_awaddr := io.aw.bits.addr
  ...
  mem.io_axi4.head.aw.bits.id := blackbox.io.m_axi_awid
  mem.io_axi4.head.aw.bits.addr := blackbox.io.m_axi_awaddr
  ...
  //not working
  val clock: Clock
  blackbox.io.clock := clock
  mem
  } 
}
```

Is there a proper way to put my verilog module between those two nodes?
How can I assign the clock to my blackbox, because this is only achievable inside a trait or module. But I assume, to connect the blackbox to memory the instantiation has to be done inside the method.

Jason

Comment: Have you tried creating a node to put between them? Generally you can't just inject Chisel in between two Diplomatic nodes, you need to insert a LazyModule and put the Chisel inside of the LazyModuleImp.

Comment: @JackKoenig Thanks for the reply. Which node would be suitable for this purpose? Two Identity Nodes? Would the connection between my blackbox and that node be made in that LazyModule?

Comment: I think `IdentityNode` is right because if I recall correctly, `IdentityNode` is for when you don't want to change any parameters on the edges. Connections from blackboxes are _always_ inside the `LazyModuleImp` (which is a `chisel3.RawModule`, as opposed to a Diplomacy `LazyModule). I think you basically have the `IdentityNode` with an edge in and edge out, then you do the actual connections of the Bundles on the edges to your `BlackBox` inside the `LazyModuleImp` (where you also instantiate the `BlackBox`).